# Interacting with OptaPlanner through CLI instead of GUI

Tags: api-design, optaplanner

I am looking for a way to **interact with OptaPlanner directly from the command line interface (CLI)** without having to use the graphical user interface (GUI).

More specifically, I am looking to pass an XML file to the Employee Rostering function,  and to get the solved XML back. Ultimately, I am looking to interact with OctaPlanner from my PHP application.

Any documentation for this?

Here is some what of an example of what I which to achieve:
 http://www.c0940097.ferozo.com/applying-optaplanner-to-everyday-problems/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI is only for the examples. Take a look at `CloudBalancingHelloWorld.java` which solves without a UI.

Or, if you're looking for a more enterprise approach, use OptaPlanner Execution Server (also ASL), which exposes everything as REST api's.